# Texture painting appears on wrong faces or not appearing at all

Tags: texture-painting

Painting appears wrongly in Material Preview and Rendered mode. It appears correctly only in Solid display mode.  Faces are in correct orientation, recalculated normals and outside too. Applied all transforms.  Tried removing and adding materials and UVMap. Still the same. First it was painted wrongly but after many attempts to correct this behavior I ended up with no texture drawing in material preview and rendered modes at all... By the way I am making this donut independently and In my second file which I did following the Donut Tutorial everything works fine.
[image]

[image]

File with texture painting issues
[image]

...and this is the one following the tutorial
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the shader editor, the image texture input is linked to the "generated" coordinates.

Plug it to "uv" or remove it (as "uv" is the default).

[image]

Without uv, Blender cannot write/map to the texture correctly.

Comment: Thank you! This has finally solved my problem.